# How to disable creation of kv_json JSON field in Oracle NoSql from spring data jpa, and have all fields in entity as key-value pairs?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, nosql, oracle-nosql

Here is the spring data oracle nosql persistence model link:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/other-databases/nosql-database/20.3/java-driver-table/persistence-model.html

[image]

In the Student entity shown in the image/from link, firstName and lastName fields are not getting created as key-value fields, instead, a kv_json JSON field is created and the firstName and lastName fields schema is present in the kv_json field.

As per the documentation,

> the fields apart from the primary key will be mapped to a single JSON
> field named kv_json

I want to **disable this feature of having kv_json JSON filed** and want to **have all java fields in the entity as columns directly like the id field in the oracle NoSQL table.**
Is there any solution to achieve this?

For a basic reference of Spring with Oracle NoSql: https://github.com/oracle/nosql-spring-sdk

Comment: Reading the documentation, the github, and as far as I understood the implementation is done using this JSON field and there is no way to do the mapping to a fixed schema or to an existing schema (disable this feature)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is confirmed. There is no way to do the mapping to a fixed schema or an existing schema. Please refer to this link with the new documentation for more information: https://github.com/oracle/nosql-spring-sdk/blob/main/README.md